# SpagoBI and MongoDB integration

Tags: mongodb, spagobi

Just wondering if anyone has integrated spago and monogdb.
If so how did you approach this problems?

Any idea wil be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It worked at-last for me. MongoDB with SpagoBI. 
All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.1.0_21012015 and installed the mongo-java-driver-3.0.0.jar

Following are the datasource configuration details :

Type: jdbc 
URL : server:port/database 
User : dbusername 
Pasword : dbpasword 
Driver: mongo

Details for dataset creation
http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/data_set